# MySQL Importing CSV but autopopulating Primary Key and Timestamp

Tags: mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I'm not very familiar with MySQL, but hopefully this is a no-brainer.

I have a table established with the following columns:

```
ID | player_name | player_role | modified
```

I have a CSV file with only this data in the columns:

```
player_name | player_role
```

How would I go about inserting all of the rows from the CSV and assigning a new PRIMARY ID and a NOW() timestamp when the entries are imported through phpMyAdmin?

*(I don't have a created field, but for the purposes of this example `modified` is set when the row is created or changed in the future).*

Comment: How many rows are in the csv file. I have these same kind of scenarios where I would kind of create a new field in the CSV files with the date and populate it with the current timestamp and if the "id " field is auto increment in the database, then it should auto populate itself.

Comment: 46 rows. I just don't know the syntax to tell it to auto-increment the PRIMARY key and to set modified to NOW(). Do I just set blank values in my CSV and it will take care of it itself?

Comment: CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255), TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)  ..something like this should work

Comment: or-- its just 46 rows. add 2 fields in the csv files with id and date and add the fields manually in excel which would make your life very easy for now